# DPRK proclamations are written in English using very nuanced (flowery) adjectives. Is this a regular part of Korean speech?

Tags: north-korean, formal

Occasionally a proclamation or statement will be issued from the Kim government. These are typically translated into English using descriptives that evoke strong negative or positive feelings. An example can be [found in this article](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jan/24/trump-national-day-of-patriotic-devotion-echoes-north-korea). I've picked out a few examples (with the flower speech I'm talking about bolded) that are particularly adjective dense, but there is a consistent pattern through all of the DPRK proclamations. As this is really the only example of Korean I am exposed to, I'm curious -- Is all Korean this flowery, is this an example of typical Korean formal speech, or is this pattern unique to the North Korean government proclamations?

---

> The **noble image** and **patriotic devotion** of the peerless patriot, who reliably defended socialism centred on the popular masses and turned [North Korea] into an **invincible politico-ideological** power and a world military power.

---

> the **spring of prosperity** under socialism will surely come … thanks to the **patriotic devotion** of Kim Jong-il, who blocked the **howling wind of history** till the last moments of his life

---

> a history of **brilliant victories** of the great leaders’ original idea of prioritising the youth and their wise leadership and **a history of ardent loyalty and patriotic devotion**, with which the young people of Korea have supported the party and the leader, the country and the people

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The North Korean government uses not only poetic words, but they also pronounce everything in a very sentimental and "epic" way. It sounds funny to South Koreans, because not even the most formal levels of speech in the South sound any closer to it.

You can watch videos of North Korean TV on Youtube to see how much effort they put into sounding like characters from a fantasy medieval kingdom proclaming royal decrees.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with user919.  The distinct, grandiose wording and delivery is common with North Korean state media, but no one in the South speaks like that, even in the most formal of settings.

(I have only ever heard that style of speaking in South Korea when used to mock the North Korean state media.)

Example of said North Korean delivery style, (daily news broadcast):

https://youtu.be/Vtr4c7Ga0jc?t=5m38s

Example of standard South Korean news:

https://youtu.be/1HWa-64k0XM?t=37m54s